# How to force correct order of expected and actual in Google Test?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

Google Test assertions `ASSERT_*` are supposed to be used in the form of `ASSERT_EQ(expected, actual)` where the 1st parameter is expected value and the 2nd is actual value. But very often I see in existing codebase that these parameters are reversed like in this code:

```
TEST(test, test)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(foo(), 1);    
}
```

This is almost ok, but it produces a bit weird error message in case of test failure like: "the result of `foo()` was expected but actually it was `1`". This seems to be a minor issue but is there any way to force correct order of expected and actual at compile time?

Comment: AFAIK - it is not a case for newer version of google-test. I mean - in newer versions - none of these sides are treated as only expected nor only actual. Just update your google test version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Hamcrest matchers from google mock:

```
ASSERT_THAT(foo(), Eq(1) );
```

This improve readability and force order of parameters.

Comment: Thanks, `ASSERT_THAT(Eq(1), foo());` indeed fails to compile.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way avoiding wired messages is, doing it correctly, from the beginning!

Okay, that doesn't help for existing test wrongly written, but in all unit-testing Frameworks I know (C#, Java, C++) it is always the same:

```
ASSERT(EXPECTED, ACTUAL)
```

And if another developer is reading your tests he should rely on you that you've done it correctly in the past.

Comment: That's the problem, you can't rely on other people that they will do it correctly.

Comment: Depends .... when working in a team and the team agrees ;-)
If it is not possible to rely on others, then also the "Hamcrest version" won't work when the other people just don't do it ;-)

Indeed the messages have been improved in latest Google Test Framework that they are "not too wrong" when used wrong order of parameters.